# Struts2 <s:select/> and a list of HashMap

Tags: java, struts2, hashmap

I have a list of HashMap in my Action class, something like {month=05, day=20, dayOfWeek=Mon}. I need to pass it to a select tag from Struts2. Generated code from page looks like this:

```
<select name="dropdown" id="form_dropdown" onchange="fsubmit();">
  <option value="{month=07, day=11, dayOfWeek=MON}">{month=07, day=11, dayOfWeek=MON}</option>
  <option value="{month=07, day=12, dayOfWeek=TUE}">{month=07, day=12, dayOfWeek=TUE}</option>
  <option value="{month=07, day=13, dayOfWeek=WED}">{month=07, day=13, dayOfWeek=WED}</option>
</select>
```

Select tag from JSP:

```
<s:select headerKey="-1" list="liveHashDaysList" name="dropdown" value="" onchange="fsubmit();" />
```

I want to make the select to display data in this form "day / month dayOfWeek" but I can't get it to work. Any advice?

Comment: I would create a class to hold the data, rather than using a HashMap. The `listKey` and `listValue` attributes of `<s:select/>` control what the value and label of the `<option/>`s are.

Comment: I agree with Steven, It's better to use bean for holding the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Bean class, that handles all this objects.

```
Integer id;
String day;
String month;
String enDayWeek;
String frDayWeek;
String frDateFormatted;
String enDateFormatted;
String year;
```

Having Constructors with and without parameters, and the getters and setters methods.

Here we have some data fields, besides that I also have two fields with the date generated as a string, to display in frontend. When I receive response from select tag, I am iterating through the days list, and index the selected object, that was a solution at the moment.